# Wrong carrier name

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-data, cellular-carriers

Two days ago I noticed that my iPhone 7 (iOS 11.2 Beta 4) switched to another (foreign) carrier. This hasn't happened in a long time but since I live near a border I thought it plausible and just tried to go to the settings to change it manually.

That's where I discovered two things:

1. My usual carrier is not appearing on the list, but the foreign one is appearing twice.
2. Even if I try to change to another carrier, the name (top left) doesn't change.

Now since that time I used my iPhone in other places and there is no change at all, the carrier name doesn't change.

I switched back to automatic selection, and noticed that it seems like the only thing wrong is the displayed name of the carrier. That is because I have roaming off and I was still getting 4G. Yesterday I used 4G like usual and on my carrier's website I could verify that this was counted as normal data usage and not roaming.

I have of course tried to restart the device but it didn't change anything. Since then I've installed Beta 5 but the problem persists.

Would anyone have an idea of what I could do? I thought of contacting my carrier but I think this is mostly a software problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hard reset (Settings -> General -> Reset -> Erase All Contents and Settings) solved the issue. I made a backup before and used it to restore my phone after the hard reset, which did no recreate the carrier issue.